# Circle collision with compound object

Tags: c++, geometry, collision-detection

I would like to do a collision detection between circle and section of a circular ring. The circle is defined by it's `position` position and it's `radius`. The other object is defined by `inner` and `outer` radius and then a `startPoint` and `endPoint` both [x, y] points.

In the examples below, `this` is the circle and `other` is the ring section.

First I just check if it's colliding with the full ring. This works without a problem.

```
float mag = this.position.Magnitude();
if (mag < other.InnerRadius() - this.radius ||
    mag > other.OuterRadius() + this.radius) {
    return false;
}
```

But then I need to check if the circle is inside or outside of the section defined by the two points. Closest I was able to get was to check if it isn't colliding with the start and end vectors, but this returns wrong results when the circle is fully inside the ring section.

```
auto dot1 = Vector::Dot(position, other.StartPoint());
auto projected1 = dot1 / Vector::Dot(other.StartPoint(), other.StartPoint()) * other.StartPoint();
auto distance1 = Vector::Distance(position, projected1);

auto dot2 = Vector::Dot(position, other.EndPoint());
auto projected2 = dot2 / Vector::Dot(other.EndPoint(), other.EndPoint()) * other.EndPoint();
auto distance2 = Vector::Distance(position, projected2);

return distance1 < radius || distance2 < radius;
```

What is the easiest way to check if a circle is colliding with a object defined by these two vectors?

[image]

**Edit:** all the point objects I'm using here are my custom `Vector` class that has implemented all the vector operations.

**Edit2:** just to clarify, the ring object has it's origin in [0, 0]

Comment: Could you be more specific about "all" the vector operations?

Comment: dot and cross product, magnitude etc.

Comment: Sounds good. Could you draw a diagram? How are the segment's corners mapping to x, y? Why not use angles?

Comment: I'm a bit confused too. If `position` is stored as a [x, y] vector, I don't understand how comparing its magnitude to the other object's radius tells you something meaningful: you'd get the same results for `-this.position` since its magnitude remains the same, but the position has moved somewhere else entirely. I may be misunderstanding this, but I hope that if I am, an explanation of how I'm reading your question will help you edit it into something more people will understand.

Comment: @ma the start and end point are calculated on object construction and then recalculated when the object is rotated around the [0, 0]. I chose this approach because I think it's better to have this information saved rather than calculate it from angles every time I check collisions.

Comment: There are two lesser questions to ask: 1) is the small circle inside, outside or intersecting this large circle? and 2) is the small circle clockwise from, counterclockwise from, or intersecting this ray? When you can answer both of those questions, you can combine the answers to find out whether the circle intersects the object.

Comment: @Beta Yes this is exactly what I need to do but I don't know how to do the second  step. I can either check if it is intersecting the rays, which I'm doing now, but then I don't know whether it's between them or not, or I can check where it is based on angles of these 2 rays, but then I don't know if it isn't too close to either of them.

Comment: @hvd the first example checks if the circle is intersecting with the ring

Comment: @MarošBeťko Ah... Looking at the picture, it starts to make sense. If the ring is around the origin (or in other words, if the position is relative to the ring's centre), then that code makes perfect sense. I didn't see that in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm.

First, let's agree on variable names:

[image: meow]

Here `r1 ≤ r2`, `-π/2 ≤ a1 ≤ a2 ≤ π/2`.

(As I was reminded in comments, you have start and end points rather than angles, but I'm going to use angles as they seem more convenient. You can easily obtain angles from points via `atan2(y-ry, x-rx)`, just make sure that `a1 ≤ a2`. Or you can rewrite the algorithm to not use angles at all.)

We need to consider 3 different cases. The case depends on where the circle center is located relative to the ring segment:

[image: meow]

In the 1st case, as you already figured, collision occurs if length of vector `(cx-rx, cy-ry)` is greater than `r1-rc` and less than `r2+rc`.

In the 2nd case collision occurs if the distane between the circle center and the closest straight edge is less than `rc`.

In the 3rd case collision occurs if the distance between the circle center and the closest of 4 corners is less than `rc`.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
rpos = vec2(rx,ry); // Ring segment center coordinates
cpos = vec2(cx,cy); // Circle coordinates

a = atan2(cy-ry, cx-rx); // Relative angle
r = length(cpos - rpos); // Distance between centers

if (a > a1 && a < a2) // Case 1
{
    does_collide = (r+rc > a1 && r-rc < a2);
}
else
{
    // Ring segment corners:
    p11 = vec2(cos(a1), sin(a1)) * r1;
    p12 = vec2(cos(a1), sin(a1)) * r2;
    p21 = vec2(cos(a2), sin(a2)) * r1;
    p22 = vec2(cos(a2), sin(a2)) * r2;

    if (((cpos-p11) · (p12-p11) > 0 && (cpos-p12) · (p11-p12) > 0) ||
        ((cpos-p21) · (p22-p21) > 0 && (cpos-p22) · (p21-p22) > 0)) // Case 2
    {
        // Normals of straight edges:
        n1 = normalize(vec2(p12.y - p11.y, p11.x - p12.x));
        n2 = normalize(vec2(p21.y - p22.y, p22.x - p21.x));

        // Distances to edges:
        d1 = n1 · (cpos - p11);
        d2 = n2 · (cpos - p21);

        does_collide = (min(d1, d2) < rc);
    }
    else // Case 3
    {
        // Squared distances to corners
        c1 = length_sqr(cpos-p11);
        c2 = length_sqr(cpos-p12);
        c3 = length_sqr(cpos-p21);
        c4 = length_sqr(cpos-p22);

        does_collide = (sqrt(min(c1, c2, c3, c4)) < rc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh. Just a few minutes before I managed to post an answer of my own, and much clearer than what I was going to post... You're ignoring the fact that the OP has the start point and end point as vectors rather than as angles. It's easy to calculate the angles from that, but it means it's not necessary to then calculate the corner positions from the angles again. But that just means the OP gets to simplify your answer a bit further, it doesn't mean there's anything wrong in your answer.

Comment: @hvd Yup, I completely disregarded that. :P I've added a notice to tell the OP they should convert to angles first or tweak the code.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the small circle to a ray:

First check to see whether the circle encloses the origin; if it does, then it intersects the ray. Otherwise, read on.

Consider the vector v from the origin to the center of the circle. Normalize that, normalize the ray R, and take the cross product Rxv. If it's positive, v is counterclockwise from R, otherwise it's clockwise from R. Either way, take acos to get the angle between them.

If the circle has radius r and its center is a distance d from the origin, then the angular half-width of the circle (as seen from the origin) is asin(r/d). If the angle between R and v is less than that, then the circle intersects the ray.

Assume that you know whether the object extends clockwise or counterclockwise from Start to End. (The numbers won't tell you that, you must know it already or the problem is unsolvable.) In your example, it's clockwise. Now you have to be careful; if the angular length of the arc is <= pi, then you can proceed, otherwise it is easier to determine whether the circle is in the smaller sector *outside* the sector of the object. But assuming the object spans less that pi, the circle is inside the sector of the object (i.e. between the rays) if and only if it is clockwise from the Start and counterclockwise from the End.